# Return string and code optimisation in F#

Tags: performance, f#, f#-interactive

How to modify below code to Return "string" so that returned output displayed on my MVC page and also would like to accept `enteredChar` from user.

Is there better way to do create this pyramid?

Current code:

```
let enteredChar = 'F' // As Interactive window doesn't support to Read Input
let mylist = ['A'..enteredChar] 
let mylistlength = mylist |> List.length
let myfunc i x tlist1 =
    (for j = 0 to mylistlength-i-2 do printf "%c" ' ')
    let a1 = [for p in tlist1  do if p < x then yield p]
    for p in a1 do printf "%c" p
    printf "%c" x
    let a2 = List.rev a1
    for p in a2 do printf "%c" p
    printfn "%s" " "

mylist |> List.iteri(fun i x -> myfunc i x mylist)
```

Output:

```
     A
    ABA
   ABCBA
  ABCDCBA
 ABCDEDCBA
ABCDEFEDCBA
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few small optimizations could be:

- Use `StringBuilder` instead of `printf` which is quite slow with long strings.
- Use `Array` instead of `List` since `Array` works better with `String`.

Here is a version producing a pyramid string, which is kept closely to your code:

```
open System
open System.Text

let generateString c = 
    let sb = StringBuilder()             
    let generate i x arr =
        String.replicate (Array.length arr-i-1) " " |> sb.Append |> ignore
        let a1 = Array.filter (fun p -> p < x) arr
        String(a1) |> sb.Append |> ignore
        sb.Append x |> ignore
        String(Array.rev a1) |> sb.Append |> ignore
        sb.AppendLine " " |> ignore

    let arr = [|'A'..c|]               
    arr |> Array.iteri(fun i x -> generate i x arr)
    sb.ToString()

generateString 'F' |> printfn "%s"
```

Comment: will be sweet if you can comment on "why Array works better with String"? Thanks

Comment: `String(a1)` is a constructor receiving an array of `char` as its parameter. Moreover, `Array` is potentially faster than `List` due to its good cache locality.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question (this likely belongs on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)) here's one way to rewrite your function:

```ml
let showPyramid (output: TextWriter) lastChar =
  let chars = [|'A' .. lastChar|]

  let getRowChars n = 
    let rec loop acc i =
      [|
        if i < n then let c = chars.[i] in yield c; yield! loop (c::acc) (i+1)
        else yield! List.tail acc
      |]
    loop [] 0

  let n = chars.Length
  for r = 1 to n do 
    output.WriteLine("{0}{1}{0}", String(' ', n - r), String(getRowChars r))
```

Example

```
showPyramid Console.Out 'F'
```

or, to output to a string

```
use output = new StringWriter()
showPyramid output 'F'
let pyramid = output.ToString()
```

#### EDIT

After seeing Tomas' answer I realized I skipped over "return a string" in your question. I updated the code and added examples to show how you could do that.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to Daniel's solution, you can achieve what you want with minimal changes to the code logic. Instead of using `printf` that writes the output to the console, you can use `Printf.bprintf` which writes the output to a specified `StringBuilder`. Then you can simply get the resulting string from the `StringBuilder`.

The modified function will look like this. I added parameter `str` and replaced `printf` with `Printf.bprintf str` (and `printfn` with `bprintf` together with additional `\n` char):

```
let myfunc i x tlist1 str = 
    (for j = 0 to mylistlength-i-2 do Printf.bprintf str "%c" ' ') 
    let a1 = [for p in tlist1  do if p < x then yield p] 
    for p in a1 do Printf.bprintf str "%c" p 
    Printf.bprintf str "%c" x 
    let a2 = List.rev a1 
    for p in a2 do Printf.bprintf str "%c" p 
    Printf.bprintf str "%s\n" " "
```

To call the function, you first create `StringBuilder` and then pass it to `myfunc` in every call. At the end, you can get the result using `ToString` method:

```
let str = StringBuilder()
mylist |> List.iteri(fun i x -> myfunc i x mylist str) 
str.ToString()
```

I think Daniel's solution looks nicer, but this is the most direct way to tunr your printing code into a string-building code (and it can be done, pretty much, using Search & Replace).

Answer (score 2):

```
let pyramid (ch:char) = 
  let ar = [| 'A'..ch |]
  let len = ar.Length
  Array.mapi
    (fun i ch -> 
      let ar = ar.[0..i]
      String.replicate (len - i - 1) " " + new string(ar) + new string((Array.rev ar).[1..]))
    ar
  |> String.concat "\n" 

pyramid 'F' |> printfn "%s"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach that seems to be a good demonstration of **functional composition**. I bet it's the shortest solution among the answers here. :)

```
let charsToString = Seq.map string >> String.concat String.Empty
let pyramid lastChar =
    let src = '-'::['A'..lastChar] |> List.toArray
    let len = Array.length src - 1

    fun row col -> row-abs(col-len+1)+1 |> max 0 |> Array.get src   // (1)
    >> Seq.init (len*2-1) >> charsToString                          // (2)
    |> Seq.init len                                                 // (3)

pyramid 'X' |> Seq.iter (printfn "%s")
```

- First, we generate an unusual array of initial data. Its element `[0]` contains a space or whatever separator you want to have; I preferred dash (`-`) for debugging purposes.
- The `(1)` line makes a function that calculates what character to be placed. The result of `row-abs(col-len+1)+1` can be either *positive* (and there is a char to be placed) or *zeronegative*, and there should be a space. Note that there is no `if`  statement: it is hidden within the `max` function;
- The `(2)` line composes a function `int -> string` for generating an individual row;
- The `(3)` line passes the function above as argument for sequence initializer.

The three lines can be written in a more verbose way:

```
    let genCell row col = row-abs(col-len+1)+1 |> max 0 |> Array.get src 
    let genRow = genCell >> Seq.init (len*2-1) >> charsToString
    Seq.init len genRow
```

Note `genRow` needs no formal argument due to functional composition: the argument is being bound into `genCell`, returning a function of a single argument, exactly what `Seq.init` needs.

Comment: I think I am not ready yet for functional composition. honesly still processing :) +1 for introducing functional composition.